# Single Sign On for API user access

Tags: single-sign-on

When Single Sign on is implemented across the org how do you enable access for admins using traditional Username/Password? Is there is profile permission?

What permission is different between admins/api users and other users that admins can login directly and other users cannot. Anything on the profile?

Answer (score 3):

As long as you do not have the login policy to prevent login using direct urls, users can still use the direct urls to login using your credentials.
[image: My Domain Login Policy]

In case the Login policy is restricted, i.e., you do prevent anyone logging in through direct url, or the identity provider is down, administrators can still login using the my domain url as below.

> https://your-domain.my.salesforce.com/**?login**

More details can be found at the documentation -- https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sso_saml_idp_values.htm&type=5

[image]

Comment: This answer can be improved by a link or source.

Comment: What permission is different between admins/api users and other users that admins can login directly and other users cannot. Anything on the profile?

Comment: There is no specific permission on profile. The differentiator between an admin vs. regular users should be that regular users when setup as SSO users, they won't won't have access to either their username or password. So even if a regular user has access to the aforementioned url, they won't be able to login. API users can still access using direct urls (which supposedly they should be allowed to).